# Python - Flask - Query String need to include '?q=' on user uploaded image file

Tags: python, flask, url, escaping, query-string

I am trying to add a date stamped query string to a users uploaded image (to bypass caching).

```
current_user.image_file = str(current_user._id) + str(file_ext) + '?q='+ dt_stmp
```

The only trouble being it ends up URL encoding those characters, and it comes out like this on request

- - [09/Sep/2020 10:41:07] "GET /static/profile_pics/1.jpg%5C%3Fq%5C%3DWed%20Sep%20%209%2010:41:07%202020 HTTP/1.1" 404

As you see it adds percentage signs to encode characters as part of safe string. I am missing a way to escape these characters so the output is more like

GET /static/profile_pics/1.jpg?q=Wed%20Sep%20%209%2010:41:07%202020 HTTP/1.1

Hope that makes sense, thanks in advance for any advice you may be able to furnish.

Comment: dt_stmp = dt_ob.strftime("%c")

Comment: Something you haven't pasted is encoding the URL.

Comment: You are right @KenKinder - I think it is this:
 image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.image_file)

I can prob add what I need as param, but it's annoying as I will have to modify DB in order to store this date value

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what is happening here, because it is part of the filename it will escape those characters as part of url_for method

```
    image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.image_file)
```

Am I right in thinking the way to solve this would be to add a date_modified value to database and append this to the end of url_for method?